# Thumbnail image border as square

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css

I have images of random sizes, all of which are less than 150x150. What I am trying for is to have a css border of 150x150 and place the image in the center of it.

```css
.thumbnail {
    display: block;
    padding: 24px 2px 24px 2px;
    
    background-color: #FFF;
    border: 1px solid #DDD;
}
```

```html
<img  style="max-width:150px;max-height:150px" data-imgpop="2" class="thumbnail img-responsive" src="http://pandatracking.com/storage/forum/thumb.php?w=150&amp;height=150">


<img  style="max-width:150px;max-height:150px" data-imgpop="2" class="thumbnail img-responsive" src="https://pandatracking.com/storage/forum/temp/admin-before.jpg">
```

If pure css solutions are not possible, jquery solutions are welcome.

EDIT : Ok as the comment suggested i tried below..but image is not center of square

```css
 
#sidebar1 { 
    width: 150px;
    height:150px;
    border: 1px solid black;
    padding: 0px 0px 0px 0px;
}

.thumbnail {  
     
}
```

```html
 
        <div id="sidebar1"><img  style="max-width:150px;max-height:150px" data-imgpop="2" class="thumbnail img-responsive" src="http://pandatracking.com/storage/forum/thumb.php?w=150&amp;height=150">
</div>
```

Comment: The correct way to do this is just using two elements, one that is 150x150px and then the image, and not try to solve it with borders.

Comment: @amenthes : that was copy pasted ,, my mistake...@adeneo : you mean with absolute ?

Comment: ok, i removed my comment. :)

Comment: @Vishnu Can you explain more about the question?

Comment: I need to have a square with border of 150x150 and inside that square i can have any random images like 150x120 or 130x150

Comment: @Vishnu Is it OK to use jquery to create the container element for each image?

Comment: @sdcr : yea , but user "tvanfosson" has answered some solution , if your solution  is efficient than that you can answer

Comment: @Vishnu no, that's it.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use a `div` to surround the image and provide the border and spacing from other elements. Then make sure you set the `line-height`, `height`, and `width` on the `div` to the size you want.  Add `text-align: center;` to the `div` and `vertical-align: middle;` to the `image`.  It's important that the image be rendered inline or the vertical spacing won't apply.  Note: I've removed the inline styling and applied it via the CSS. I would recommend that you avoid inline styling.

Working fiddle at http://jsfiddle.net/45kofx24/

```css
.thumbnail {
    display: block;
    background-color: #FFF;
    border: 1px solid #DDD;
    width: 150px;
    height: 150px;
    margin: 24px 2px 24px 2px;
    line-height: 150px;
    text-align: center;
}

.thumbnail img {
    max-width: 150px;
    max-height: 150px;
    vertical-align: middle;
}
```

```html
<div class="thumbnail">
    <img data-imgpop="2" class="img-responsive" src="http://pandatracking.com/storage/forum/thumb.php?w=150&amp;height=150">
</div>
<div class="thumbnail">
    <img data-imgpop="2" class="img-responsive" src="https://pandatracking.com/storage/forum/temp/admin-before.jpg">
</div>
```

Answer (score 2):

If you surround each image by a `div` and set the border of that, then you might be able to have make an image less than 150px 150px into a container, `div`.

In other words, surround each image by a `div` with height and width of 150px and inside that put an image.

Comment: This thing is explained in comment already , please delete it.

Comment: Julian, I gave you a +1, don't be sad.

Comment: @sdcr : your comment made me give him another +1 :p